# Why my callback form validation function not working?

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration, hmvc

I recently upgraded my CI to 3.1.6 and use HMVC.

With my last CI version (MVC only) the callback worked well. But now the callback seems not to work. For example even with correct password input it keeps showing an error message.

here is my controller:(auto-loaded libraries and helpers)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends MX_Controller {
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('m_login');
    $this->load->model('m_profile');    
}
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}
public function loginPage(){        
    $this->load->view('login');
}
//---validasi login---
function loginAction(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|alpha_dash|required|min_length[5]|max_length[18]',
            array(
                    'min_length'      => '%s anda kurang dari 5 karakter',
                    'alpha_dash' => '%s anda mengandung karakter yang tidak diizinkan'
            )
    );
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|min_length[8]|max_length[20]|callback_password_check',
            array(
                'min_length' => '%s anda kurang dari 8 karakter',
                'password_check' => '%s anda harus mengandung huruf dan angka',
                'max_length' => '%s maximal berjumlah 20 karakter'
            )
    );

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
    $this->load->view('login');
            }
            else
            {
    $where = array(
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => md5($password)
    );

    $cek = $this->m_login->cek_login("user_pb",$where)->num_rows();
    if($cek > 0){
        $data_session = array(
            'nama' => $username,
            'status' => "login"
            );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);

        redirect(base_url("admin/admin_page"));
    }else{      
        print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert('Username atau password salah!');</script>";
        $this->load->view('login');         
    }
    }
}
```

here my callback function, below the loginAction:

```
public function password_check($str)
    {
       if (preg_match('#[0-9]#', $str) && preg_match('#[a-zA-Z]#', $str)) {
         return TRUE;
       }
       return TRUE;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just wondering, why put the same output inside the if clause as outside?

Comment: @mega6382 this is working in my previous mvc CI

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: password_check error ('password_check' => '%s anda harus mengandung huruf dan angka'). the error message means 'you should put alphabet and number in your password'. i have type the correct pass and follow the rules, but it always show error. @mega6382